User space program for assembling Linux MD RAID disk images into a coalesced disk image, without using kernel implementation
I've been handed a set of disk images which apparently are Linux MD RAID, asking if I could "reassemble" them. Using a Linux kernel it's as easy as attaching them into partition scanned loopback devices (losetup -fP <diskimage>) and then have the kernel assemble them, by issuing the right mdadm stanza.
However, I was wondering if there's a tool that would take a bunch of Linux MD RAID images assembling and digesting it into a mountable disk image file.
My main motivation is, that assembling via kernel might cause user whoopsies on a system that nominally uses MD RAID and you'd have to spin up a dedicated VM if you'd want to isolate the process. And this seems like a kludge that rubs me the wrong way.

Not sure if there is a tool. For RAID 1 you can simply mount at an offset. For RAID 0 you can pretty much use split and cat. For RAID 5/6 you have to figure out how to skip over parity. For missing drives you have to figure out how to recalculate from parity. It's not all that hard to write in any programming language but there's a lot of little details to consider. Not sure what the point is if you can just use mdadm for the job. Especially if it's actually mdadm array and metadata present and everything. Spinning up a VM is easy, and usually not even necessary.
